# "in sort of a fit of" - Meaning

Tags: meaning

What does "in sort of a fit of" mean here :

> Suddenly, this other kid from Harvard, named Mark, had this product called Facebook and people being excited about it.  So ***in sort of a fit of*** somewhat immature professional jealousy, I said, "I'm not going to use this thing."

Comment: Have you consulted a dictionary? *Fit* is used here in the sense of an involuntary episode of a physical or emotional affliction, and the *of* PP is its complement, designating the affliction undergone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*"A fit of X"* means an episode, or instance of that emotion.  So "a fit of professional jealousy" is a particular moment where the person was overcome by jealousy.  Similarly you can say "a fit of rage", "a fit of passion" and pretty much any other strong feeling:

> In **a fit of spite**, he took her car and drove it into the ocean.

*"(A) sort of a ..."* is a standard phrase to say something is *like* something else, or that it is similar, but not quite the same:

> He was **sort of a** good student, in that he got good grades, but he showed little interest in what he was studying and promptly forgot everything at the end of each semester.

In many cases "a sort of" is simply a figure of speech used when the speaker wants to *soften* or *qualify* an otherwise harsh comment:

> I wouldn't say the politician is *stupid*, but he's **sort of an** idiot.

Comment: I upvoted this answer, but feel compelled to add that "in sort of a fit of" would mean something that somehow resembles a fit of jealousy, but is in fact not quite a true fit of jealousy. (Perhaps the "sort of" part is meant to convey that this "fit of jealousy" is a bit of hyperbole and is being used humorously?) Moreover, just like _sort of_ can "soften" _a fit of,_ I think _somewhat_ "softens" _immature_.

Comment: @J.R.  I would say rather that the author is doubly qualifying his statement, which (as he should have learned in grade school) only weakens his argument and makes him sound indecisive.

Comment: Andrew: I more than somewhat sort of agree with that assessment.

Comment: @Andrew thank  you so much , it's so clear for me after your answer